# Intel Pin: how are routines actually instrumented?

Tags: c++, intel-pin

I was wondering how Intel Pin instruments routines.

More specifically, when calling RTN_InsertCall with IPOINT_BEFORE, the instrumentation occurs just before the call instruction to the function or also for jump instructions to the function?

I am asking this because I am writing a Pintool in which I am instrumenting routines before and after they are called.

Although I know for a fact from Pin's user manual that IPOINT_AFTER does not guarantee success, there are also cases where, for some routines, only the analysis function for IPOINT_AFTER is called without calling first the analysis routine for IPOINT_BEFORE. So I was wondering what could be the cause of this phenomenon.